# Validate form post in same modal dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dialog, validation

I've been experimenting with mvc forms and jquery for a couple of days now, and found some interesting results.

I have a form with a file upload in a view.  Once the form is submitted, I use model validation to ensure that the file is not empty, it's of the permitted type, etc.  If model validation fails, I can return the model to the view (the same view), and display the errors in the validation summary quite nicely.  Here is my code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("TestView", "TestController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",  @id = "ImportFile"}))
    {    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "")

        <span id="instructions">Select a File to Import:</span><br />           
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.UploadedFile, new { style = "width:275px;", type = "file", @id = "UploadedFile", @name = "UploadedFile" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.UploadedFile)
        <span style="font-size: 8pt">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.HeadersIncluded)
            First Column Includes Headers?</span>
        <p style="margin-bottom: 7px;">
            <input type="submit" name="launchbutton" value="Continue" class="InnerButton"/></p>
    } 
<div id="UploadPartial"></div>
```

and my controller methods here:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public ActionResult TestView()
    {
        TestViewModel testModel = new TestViewModel();
        testModel.HeadersIncluded = true;
        return View(testModel);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult TestView(TestViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             return View(model);
       }
        else
        {
             return View(model);
        }
    }
```

With that, all is well, and if the model is valid, or not the original form is undisturbed (with the exception of validation errors), and I have been able to load a partial view to the same page with a jquery post, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UploadPartial').load('@Url.Content("~/TestController/TestView2")', function() {
    });
```

In other words, if the Model is valid, load another additional partial view.

So then I wondered, can I do this within a modal dialog?  In other words, can I have the form opened in a modal dialog, submit it, perform the model validation, then have the results returned to the modal dialog . . .

What happens is, when the Model is validated, the results are posted back to a blank page.  There is no layout, no script files, just a blank page containing the form (with validation errors if present).  I tried returning View, PartialView, modifying the layout of the view, adding the necessary script files, etc.  I use the same form code (but from within a dialog), and after submit, I can see that the Model Validation does happen, and if the model validation is successful, or not, I want to simply return the same View or PartialView to the same dialog with either the validation errors, or additional information (within the model) so that I may proceed to the next step (which would be loading another view).  Here is my controller code for that:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public ActionResult TestView()
    {
        TestViewModel testModel = new TestViewModel();
        testModel.HeadersIncluded = true;
        return PartialView(testModel);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult TestView(TestViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("TestView", model);

        }
        else
        {
             return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
```

I've tried returning PartialView, View, changing the ActionResult to PartialViewResult, but I am not able to return the  now Partial View to the modal dialog that the form is in.  The Partial View is being returned, but just to a blank page with no formatting, instead of the modal dialog I want it in.  Seems that the modal dialog disappears, and all of the site formatting with it.

So my question is, is this even possible?  Can you submit a form within a modal dialog, and have the results of that form submit returned to the same dialog (after model validation has been performed), and still have the formatting of the site with the necessary script files needed to process further jquery.

Thanks, and let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: i dont know the answer , but would like to know. any experts around?

Comment: i am facing same issue. were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a content div inside my dialog div and have the jQuery populate the content div from the partial view.

You could also use the Ajax.BeginForm helper with the UpdateTargetId set to the content div.

The other hurtle when your form is in a jQuery dialog is you must retrigger the validation after the content has been updated via Ajax.  Something like
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");